# Почему Spring Security не отдает страницу логина?

Tags: java, spring-security

Есть страница авторизации которую Spring Security должен отдать но что-то идет не так и я получаю `404`. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем моя ошибка.

Вот мой крнтроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
    if (error != null) {...}
    if (logout != null) {...}

    return "login";
}
```

Это мои Spring Security конфигурации:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("user");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Spring MVC конфиг:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.pravvich")
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        /* This resources relation webapp. Its NOT java/resources !!! */
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver =
                new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
}
```

Конфигурация где искать компоненты:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.pravvich")
public class SpringRootConfig {
}
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

И структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что за `error` и `logout` у метода логин в контроллере?

Comment: @MrFylypenko обработка ошибок и выход. они пока будут null все равно проблема с доступом к странице.

Comment: Могу посоветовать посмотреть видеороуроки от O'Reilly, показано все, начиная от Base64, csrf, правильной валидации и заканчивая кастомными настройками всего spring security.

Comment: @alexandr gaiduchok а не подскажите как канал называется?

Comment: Вот ссылка на оф сайт а как получить их я думаю вы разберетесь http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920045229.do

Comment: Контроллер то ваш видно, а где видно что это вообще бин?? мало реквест маппинга, нужно как минимум пометить его класс @Controller или что-то в этом духе